# Mix up between UIGestureRecogniser and touchesBegan

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I'm using both `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and `touchesBegan` in a SpriteKit scene.  UISwipeGestureRecogniser is initiated in `didMoveToView()`:

```
let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
swipeRight.direction = .Right
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
swipeLeft.direction = .Left
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```

`touchesBegan()` is used to transition to another scene when nodes are touched.  The nodes are identified by their names, in some cases by the prefix to their name.

```
if (node.name?.hasPrefix("enemy") != nil) {
    let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(StandardSettings.SceneManager.transitionDuration)
    let enemyScene = EnemyScene(size: self.frame.size)
                    enemyScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    view?.presentScene(enemyScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Finally, there are functions for swipedRight() and swipedLeft().  These move an SKShapeNode from left to right (or the reverse).

```
func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {            
shapeNode.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: 0, duration: 5.0))
}
```

This all works well, except when a node, identified by it's prefix is touched during a swipe movement.  When there's no contact with the node, the shapeNode moves across the screen as expected.  When there is contact, the transition code to a new scene is also being called.  It seems this is only happening when the enemy node is being identified by its name's prefix.  Nodes identified by a full name comparison with a string don;t seem to have this issue.  Is there a way to disable `touchesBegan()` while the code executes a swipe-triggered method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to determine if a touch event is a swipe gesture or a simple touch is to test the distance between the starting and ending touch locations. The following is an example of how to do this.

First, define a variable that stores the initial touch position

```
var touchStart:CGPoint?
```

and a constant to test the distance between the touch locations. Adjust this value as needed.

```
let minSwipeDistance:CGFloat = 22
```

In the `touchesBegan` method, store the initial touch location

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        touchStart = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}
```

and in `touchesEnded`, compare the distance between the current and initial touch locations. If this distance is relatively small, the event is not a swipe.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first, start = touchStart {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        // Compute the distance between the two touches
        let dx = location.x - start.x
        let dy = location.y - start.y
        let distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        if distance < minSwipeDistance {
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
            if let name = node.name where name.hasPrefix("enemy") {
                print ("transition to new scene")
            }
        }
    }
    // Reset the initial location
    touchStart = nil
}
```

Comment: Appreciate that. I found after implementing the solution proposal that the problem was repeated.  My conclusion is that Apple have already implemented something like this under the hood.  I traced the problem however.  It comes from a change in Swift2.  In the "old" swift, I had just looked for a prefix for nodes.

Comment: iOS doesn't disable individual touch events during a swipe gesture because it doesn't know in advance that the gesture will be a swipe until the user's finger moves a set distance. You can test this by starting your swipe on an `enemy`. In this case, the scene will transition even with the updated `hasPrefix` code. I've updated my answer to add the `hasPrefix` test.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a better approach than mine.  I was leaning on the user avoiding touching an enemy node when starting a swipe.  I had a second problem which was due to the != nil test suggested by the editor for hasPrefix effectively meant that any node w/o a name was being treated as an enemy node.  This problem triggered the transition's expected from an enemy node.  Now both issues are fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from a change in Swift2.  In the "old" swift, I had just looked for a prefix for nodes...  `if (node.name?.hasPrefix("enemy"))`  With the upgrade to Swift2, I followed the recommended changes in the editor and added `if (node.name?.hasPrefix("enemy") != nil)`  I understand now, this effectively makes the prefix test meaningless.  The solution I've used is to force the declaration `if (node.name!.hasPrefix("enemy"))` with the caveat that I need to make sure now that all SKNode's have a name property.